# WPF ListView Dynamically change control based on selected row

Tags: wpf, listview

VS 2019 .net framework 4.7, using MVVM

I have a ListView with two columns.  One to display text (TextBlock) and a ComboBox to display a selection.  One requirement is, the ComboBox displays a dynamic list of choices, based on the row currently selected.  I've got that working, sort of.  When the selected row changes, the correct list populates the comboBox and the user can select an option.  However, the selected item from the comboBox doesn't persist when the row changes.

As a workaround, I've considered changing the ComboBox to a TextBlock, when the selected row loses focus.  From what I've been reading, it looks like Triggers might do the trick.  I've looked at examples how to define the trigger but I'm not sure how to implement this where ListView columns are defined.

I have a few questions. Does this sound like a good approach, is there a simpler way to accomplish what I need?

If what I've suggested sounds ok, how to implement this in the ListView column definition section?

Thanks in advance...

Expecting the comboBox to retain the users selection, when the row loses focus.

Comment: Usually you bind the SelectedItem to a data model (the item). Because ListView uses virtualization the item container gets unloaded when scrolled out of view and loaded again when scrolled into view. If you want any help you must post a minimal example that we can review in order to identify what you did wrong.